# I've connected to my WiFi but internet is not working!

Tags: wireless, network-manager, internet

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcuQc.jpg)

I have windows dual booted with Ubuntu on this laptop.

I've internet access on windows but not on Ubuntu.

Tried USB tethering, it doesn't work.
Version: 20.04.3 LTS

About my wifi adapter-
Product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
Vender: Qualcomm Atheros
Clock: 33MHz

Please help me out here!!

Comment: Can you please post what happens when you try to connect? Is it connecting to the network but no access, or not connecting at all? If connecting, the first thing to do is check which network it’s connecting to - open settings (click on the top right of the screen) - in case it’s connecting automatically to a wifi point which doesn’t have internet capability.

Comment: It connects to my own wifi with signal status as "Excellent".

Comment: Please edit your question to show the results of these terminal commands: `ping -c1 8.8.8.8` and: `ping -c1 www.ubuntu.com` and finally: `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: (Response to ping -c1 8.8.8.8)

Comment: PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data. 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=118 time=414ms

Comment: --- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics --- 1 packet transmitted, 1 recieved, 0% packect loss, time 0ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 414.127/414.127/414.127/0.00 ms

Comment: (Response to ping -c1 www.ubuntu.com)

Comment: ping: www.ubuntu.com: Temporary failure in name resolution

Comment: (Response to ls -al /etc/resolv.conf)

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep 16 14:39 /etc/resolv.config

Answer (score 0):

Please do:

```
sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.con*
ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

Reboot and tell us if there is any improvement.

Comment: Output-> unable to resolve host valerie: Temporary failure in name resolution

Comment: Is that the response when you simply tried to issue the command with sudo? If so, please show us: `cat /etc/hosts` and also: `cat /etc/hostname`

Comment: Anyways thank you @chili555 for your support, I uninstalled my ubuntu. I'm now using pop os by system76!